# Getting error trying to redirect a page to login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am getting this error when trying to redirect my page to the login page.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
    //0 Username | 1 Fullname | 2 User Id | 3 Login Type | 4 Election Id
    string[] UserData = ticket.UserData.Split('|');

    if (UserData[3] == null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("login", "login");
    }
```

And the error is :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 22:  Line 23:         public ActionResult Index() { Line 24:
>   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
>   FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
>   Line 25:             //0 Username | 1 Fullname | 2 User Id | 3 Login
>   Type | 4 Election Id Line 26:             string[] UserData =
>   ticket.UserData.Split('|');
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Elections\Elections2014\Controllers\ffs\ffsInventoryController.cs
>   Line: 24

Comment: debug and check if `Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value` has a value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ticket` seems to be null. That's why you get a NullPointerException in the moment you want to split the UserData. `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt()` returns null if the encryptedTicket parameter is not a valid ticket.

Have a look at: [FormsAuthentication.Decrypt Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

`Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value` should return a valid encryptedTicket-String. In your case it seems to be that is doesn't return a valid string.

Comment: So how should I handle this if it is returning a null value?

Comment: Have a look at the example code provided by microsoft about how to loop cookies: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 Maybe this will help you understanding your mistake.